# Why is recursion slower than filter with this Random number counter

Tags: haskell

I am writing a function that generates a million random numbers of 1 or 0 and then counts how many 0s were generated.

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad

countZeros :: Int -> IO Int
countZeros n = (length . filter (==0)) <$> (replicateM n $ randomRIO (0,1 :: Int))

countZeros' :: Int -> IO Int
countZeros' n = go n 0 
  where
    go :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
    go x acc = do
      r  <- randomRIO (0,1 :: Int)
      case x of
        0 -> pure acc
        _ -> let acc' = if r == 0 then succ acc else acc
             in  go (pred x) acc'
```

when I run the functions with an input of 1000000

```
>λ= countZeros 1000000
499716
(0.93 secs, 789,015,080 bytes)

>λ= countZeros' 1000000
500442
(2.02 secs, 1,109,569,560 bytes)
```

I don't understand why the prime function is twice as slow as the other. I assumed that they are essentially doing the same thing behind the scenes.

I am using GHCi.

What am I missing?

Comment: `[succ, id] !! r $ acc` is the standout to me: it looks needlessly expensive to build a list just to index into it. Why not replace with a case on `r`, or use `== 0` like the other version?

Comment: Also, timing and performance in ghci does not correlate with performance of the compiled code.  When you care about performance be sure you compile and run tests via machine code preferably with `-O2`.

Comment: Make `go` strict on the accumulator, to avoid building large thunks.

Comment: The implementation of `replicateM` somehow matters. Replacing it with a local implementation (but identical to the library one) makes the fast version just as slow. I think it may just be that GHCi doesn't optimize as well as the library code is optimized.

Comment: @amalloy it is not that expensive. At least not to the point to make a difference here. Nevertheless I have changed it  and it makes no difference.

Comment: @chi how do I do that?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way is to add `go _ acc | seq acc False = undefined` right after `go :: Int -> Int -> IO Int`.

Comment: @chi that does not compile...

Comment: try `go x !acc = do ...`. you might need to add [`{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}`](https://ocharles.org.uk/posts/2014-12-05-bang-patterns.html) at the top of your source file.

Comment: @WillNess I have tried that... made no difference :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [bang patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#bang-patterns-informal), and proper compilation with `-O2`, the "prime" function is faster:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where

import System.Random
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment

countZeros :: Int -> IO Int
countZeros n = (length . filter (==0)) <$> (replicateM n $ randomRIO (0,1 :: Int))

countZeros' :: Int -> IO Int
countZeros' n = go n 0 
  where
    go :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
    go !x !acc = do
      r  <- randomRIO (0,1 :: Int)
      case x of
        0 -> pure acc
        _ -> let acc' = if r == 0 then succ acc else acc
             in  go (pred x) acc'

main :: IO ()
main = do
   [what] <- getArgs
   let n = 1000 * 1000 * 10
       fun = case what of
          "1" -> countZeros
          "2" -> countZeros'
          _   -> error "arg not a number"
   putStrLn "----"
   print =<< fun n
   putStrLn "----"
```

Compiled with

```
$ stack ghc -- RandomPerf.hs -O2 -Wall
$ stack ghc -- --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.3
```

Tests:

```
$ time ./RandomPerf.exe 1
----
4999482
----

real    0m3.329s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s
$ time ./RandomPerf.exe 2
----
5001089
----

real    0m2.338s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.046s
```

Repeating the tests gives comparable results, so this is not a fluke.

Result: the `countZeros'` function is significantly faster.

Using Criterion and running a proper benchmark is left as an exercise.

You probably used GHCi to assess performance, which prevents the optimizer to do its job. GHCi sacrifices proper optimization to load files faster, and be more usable in an interactive way.

Answer (score 2):

These actually work in different ways from each other, at a level that matters. And both are slow.

The version using `replicateM` is bad because `replicateM` in `IO` can't stream its results. The entire list will be constructed at once, before `filter` and `length` get to start operating on it. The reason it's faster is that `length` is strict in its accumulator, so it doesn't generate a massive nested chain of thinks the way your other version does. And that's even worse for performance.

The recursive version doesn't use a strict accumulator. This means that the value it returns is a giant chain of nested thunks, holding on to all the generated entries and a bunch of indirect calls via list indexing. This is even more memory used than the filter version, because it's holding on to a bunch of closures as well as all the values. But even with that fixed, it would still be slow. Using `!!` just wrecks performance. It's recursive when a simple if would do the same job much more efficiently.

Comment: The `if then else` version has little or no impact in these timings. I have changed it because someone else also commented about it. Would it be possible for you to write an efficient way to do what I am doing?

Comment: @matthias the smallest change is enabling BangPatterns and throwing a ! on `acc` in the second pattern match. Probably good enough to get ghc to generate the best code, at least when you're working outside of ghci so you can enable optimizations.